# retrieving the text property of dropdownlist but I get the text of the initial dropdown item

Tags: c#

I have a dropdown list containing the list of my gridview items by ID. When I select an item and try to delete it, the initial item that was shown gets deleted instead of the item I select. Here's my delete item code:-

```
    protected void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] titleAndID = DropDownList1.Text.Split(new string[] { "-_-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string ID = titleAndID[1];
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from lol_list where ID=@ID", conn);
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
        conn.Close();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        string picPath = Server.MapPath("~/wPics/") + dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();

        if (File.Exists(picPath))
            File.Delete(picPath);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from lol_list where ID=@ID", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        populate_dd();
        Label1.Text = "Deleted!";
        Label1.Visible = true;
        lbl_error.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_error.Text = ex.Message;
        lbl_error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to close connection before your DataAdapter fills the DataTable. Doesn't that throws an exception?

Comment: any reason you're not just binding the dropdown to a collection and using selecteditem?

Comment: did you inspect the debugger to see what value "ID" is? you are getting just the first item in the list by default and splitting it. that is by default the selected item...

Comment: It takes the text of the dropdown of the item that is initially on display

Comment: Are you re-populating the ddl before this method is called?

Comment: yes the the dropdown was populated with every postback in page_load event, its fixed now, thanks @ShaiCohen